# How does 32bit and 64bit DLLs link to the same C:\system32\kernel32.DLL?

Tags: windows, dll, 32bit-64bit

I was sure 64bit DLL cannot link to 32bit DLL.

Comment: IIRC this has to do with the virtual mapping shenanigans Windows does in newer versions. One DLL path can result in dozens of different versions depending on who's asking.

Comment: A DLL is linked to kernel32.lib, not kernel32.dll.  The actual DLL that gets loaded at runtime is another story, told by Sophia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow64 has a file redirector. It has the same named dlls but are stored in the appropriate location. The concept is explained at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx

The %windir%\System32 directory is reserved for 64-bit applications. Most DLL file names were not changed when 64-bit versions of the DLLs were created, so 32-bit versions of the DLLs are stored in a different directory. WOW64 hides this difference using a file system redirector.

In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64. Access to %windir%\lastgood\system32 is redirected to %windir%\lastgood\SysWOW64. Access to %windir%\regedit.exe is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe.